# Apache Spark multiple context error

Tags: tomcat, apache-spark

I have one spark web application which I am trying to deploy on tomcat.
But when I am trying to start spark using rest calls it giving following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
Actually Spark was already started from other user so when I was starting it with my user it was giving multiple context error. After stopping from other user account, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably doing something like this

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
val sc1 = new SparkContext(conf)
...
val sc2 = new SparkContext(conf) // <<<< HERE
```

You should use *only one* context, e.g.

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
...
sc.DoSomething()
sc.DoSomethingElse() // see, it is the same context
```

Comment: i did the same thing . now its giving error like:
File file:/home/user/checkpoint/351bac20-e6d5-41bc-be15-79070b31dbb3 does not exist. but /home/user/checkpoint directory is present.

Comment: @user3359790 how many workers do you have? If more than one you'd have to replicate data to all of them. Alternatively you can use Hadoop HDFS fily system and write/read your files from it. It's a distributed file system and will work on all the nodes as if it's just one node

Comment: @user3359790 do you have 1 master and 1 salve or 1 (master-slave) configuration? Double check that directory is present on the *slave*.

Comment: I have one ubutnu vm and i am running both master and worker on same machine i.e localhost. In this case both will use same chekpoint directory or it will be different for master and slave?

Comment: Should be the same then. You have also used absolute path (path starting with a slash `/home...`. From your first comment I can see that /home/user/checkpoint/ **351bac20-e6d5-41bc-be15-79070b31dbb3** is not found and then you say that /home/user/checkpoint exists. But check the last bits (in bold). Try doing `cd /home/user/checkpoint/351bac20-e6d5-41bc-be15-79070b31dbb3` can you change dir there?

Comment: yes  351bac20-e6d5-41bc-be15-79070b31dbb3 dir is not present. but this directory use to change every time i try to run the program. so error comes like /home/user/checkpoint/<some_dir> doesnot exists. i am not sure why it not present. Most important thing if i try to run the program from eclipse and local tomcat it working.

Comment: Looks like the code that should create that directory is not running as you would expect it to. Who is responsible for creating this dir?

Comment: I think it is internal to spark. i just need to declare sc.checkpoint("directory") and it will be handled by spark

Comment: I think you will only be using checkpoint call if you had a multi-node cluster setup and you wanted to preserve the state of operations, in case one of the node dies, so that the others can read checkpoint directory and restore the state of the failing node to resume work. Is this what you trying to test? Why do you use checkpoint?

Comment: Currently i am testing it in my local . if it works our plan is to deploy it on distributed spark cluster. Moreover if i will not define chekpoint directory at runtime it use to give error like "checkpoint directory not set".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, and moving out SparkContext into new object helped.

```scala
  def spark = Action {
    val logFile = "README.md"
    val logData = SparkConnector.sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numSparks = logData.filter(line => line.contains("POST")).count()
    Ok(views.html.spark("Lines with Spark: " + numSparks))
  }
```

**SparkConnector.scala**

```scala
object SparkConnector {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Application", "/opt/spark-1.5.2", List("target/scala-2.11/app_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"))
}
```